# All of sudden Google Sign in is not working in few devices like One plus and Samsung Galaxy

Tags: java, android

I am using Google sign in for user login purpose and it works on all models except few models of Oneplus, Samsung galaxy and huawei devices.

This is happening for last few days.

It is showing permission page in a loop and I can't proceed further.
Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you, and I managed to fix it, by removing the `requestServerAuthCode(clientId, true)` from the `GoogleSignInOptions`.